# The meaning of phrase 「すこしじつ」

Tags: meaning

A few minutes ago on TV I heard the phrase 「すこしじつ」. The broadcast is about cuisine 「料理」. Maybe I misheard it, because I can not translate it in vocabularies..
I think it begins with 「少{すこ}し」, then..?

Comment: I wish you did not "correct" the Japanese phrase in the thread title after reading my answer.  What is the point of it?

Comment: I think it will be useful when someone will search the questions, as a keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure what you heard was 「すこし**ず**つ」, meaning "little by little".

「すこし**じ**つ」 makes no sense.

「ずつ」, which is a particle, by itself means "per", "at the rate of", etc.

For instance, 「[毎月]{まいつき}３[度]{ど}ずつ」 means "3 times a (or per) month".